# Apache Rewrite How do I redirect url by replacing part of it?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Take this url for example:

```
 www.mysite.com/old/blablabla/some.html
```

I want to replace any request uri starting with `/old/` with `/new/old/`.
Then that sample should be

```
 www.mysite.com/new/old/blablabla/some.html
```

I tried this but I got 404：

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/old/
RewriteRule ^/old/(.*)$ /new/old/$1 [L]
```

Comment: You can omit the `RewriteCond`, it's redundant; the `RewriteRule` is already matching against `^/old/`. Beyond that, it's hard to say why *the file wasn't found*, since we can't verify that it should be where you think it is.

Comment: Does the url /new/old/foo exist?

Answer (score 0):

Just with this:

```
RewriteRule ^/old/(.*) /new/old/$1 [L]
```

but `/new/old/blablabla/some.html` has to exist phisicaly in your server path.